# finding sprite position relative to background image

Tags: android, image, scroll

can anyone tell me how to find out the relative position of a sprite image with respect to a background image?
i.e. when the background is panned (scrolled) the image should move along with the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay...for making the sprite movce along with the background when scrolled, 
the code is:

initialize

```
PointF touchStart = new PointF();
PointF picStart = new PointF();
PointF prevPicStart = new PointF();
```

and implement this in the onTouchEvent() method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch (ev.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            touchStart.set(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            x = ev.getX();
            y = ev.getY();

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

        newX = ev.getX() - touchStart.x + prevPicStart.x;
        newY = ev.getY() - touchStart.y + prevPicStart.y;

        if ((newX <= 0 && newX > 0 - BG_image.getWidth() + ActivityClass.DISP_WIDTH)) {
            picStart.x = newX;
        }

        if ((newY <= 0 && newY > 0 - BG_image.getHeight() + ActivityClass.DISP_HEIGHT)) {
            picStart.y = newY;
        }

        invalidate();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        prevPicStart.x = picStart.x;
        prevPicStart.y = picStart.y;

        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

onDraw() method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBG_l1, picStart.x, picStart.y, paint);

    canvas.translate(picStart.x, picStart.y);
   person.draw(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the Sprite a child of the background image?  If not, you can use a method called localtoGlobal which converts the point object from the  Sprite's (local) coordinates to the background's (global) coordinates.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29

Comment: This is tagged as an android question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use virtual x and y sprite positions, and have an origin x and y position (which would be the top left of the screen).

When you want to scroll your screen, you just modify the origin x and y position.

Then anywhere you draw something to the screen, you need to subtract the origin position from the virtual position.

Eg.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x - originX, y - originY, paint);
```

Whenever you move any sprite you manipulate their 'virtual' x and y positions. If you translate the virtual x, y to actual screen x, y by subtracting the origin everything will move together.

Now for example, if you wanted your background to scroll from right to left, you'd just add to originX every frame.

Comment: modify the origin X and Y? won't that re-draw the whole image from that point?
and example will be helpful.

Comment: Yes it will redraw the whole image, that's the basis for a scrolling background.